# How do you get rid of question marks in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame with missing values marked with a "?"

Is there any way to replace all the "?" with either a '0' or NA value?

Ideally I want to replace them with zeroes as the rest of the values are numeric.

Comment: You can use `na.strings='?'` in `read.csv/read.table` to automatically convert those into `NA` while reading the dataset.  If it is missing value, it is better to convert to `NA` instead of `0` as there could be values that are 0 in the dataset.

Comment: Just use `as.numeric` on the relevant columns.